# iTextSharp Dll not printing with my passing html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

```
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(PDFText);

    //Create PDF document
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(doc);


    string PDF_FileName = Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/PDF_File.pdf";

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(PDF_FileName, FileMode.Create));

    doc.Open();

    doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a Red Font Test using Times Roman", times));

    try

    {

        parser.Parse(reader);

    }
```

This is converted in pdf but it gives some other fonts like big letters and properly not aligned.

Comment: Please provide a *small* sample of the HTML that you are trying to parse. Also, the `HTMLWorker` is deprecated in favor of `XMLWorker`, have you tried that?

Comment: I not tried XMLWorker, ok let me know whether its working or not.